# Rails: Changing name for a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cloud9-ide

I'm creating a database website using rails. I implemented where a user can upload an image. There are two places where you can upload an image, one for a vendor and other for the inventory. One of the model is called "photos" and the other "fotos". I'm new to rails and wasn't sure how to use the same model, "photos" to upload to the other part of the database, so I created the model "foto" and followed the tutorial. But now when you upload a photo, the button says "Create Foto". I want it to say "Create Photo". I'm not sure how to do this.

Some of my code files

_form.html.erb/fotos/view

```
 <%= form_for([@vendor, @vendor.fotos.build]) do |f| %>
   <div class="form-group1">
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image, class: 'form-control1'%>
 </div>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
    <% end %>
```

_foto.html.erb/fotos/view

```
<div class="media1">
  <div class="media-left1">
    <%= link_to image_tag(foto.image.url, class: 'media-object1'), foto.image.url, target: '_blank' %>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body1">
    <h4 class="media-heading1"><%= foto.title %></h4>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
    <%= link_to 'Delete Photo', [foto.vendor, foto],
                                method: :delete,
                                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

show.html.erb/vendors/view

```
<body>
    <div class = "head">
        <h1>Vendor Information</h1>
        <div class = "image1" >
             <img src= "http://dx.deucex.com/i/logo.png" >
        </div>
    </div>   
</body> 

<%= render @vendor.fotos %>

<h3>Add a photo:</h3>
<%= render 'fotos/form' %>

<p>
    <strong>Company:</strong>
    <%= @vendor.company %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Contact Name:</strong>
    <%= @vendor.contact_name %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Phone:</strong>
    <%= @vendor.phone %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Email:</strong>
    <%= @vendor.email %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>MOQ:</strong>
    <%= @vendor.moq %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Cost/Item:</strong>
    <%= @vendor.cost_per_item %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Payment Method:</strong>
    <%= @vendor.payment_method %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Terms:</strong>
    <%= @vendor.terms %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Turnover Period:</strong>
    <%= @vendor.turnover %>
</p>    

<p>
    <strong>Returns:</strong>
    <%= @vendor.returns %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Notes:</strong>
    <%= @vendor.notes %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Back', vendors_path %>
```

fotos_controller.rb

```
class FotosController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @fotos = Foto.order('created_at')
 end

 def new
  @foto = Foto.new
 end

 def create
    @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
    @foto = @vendor.fotos.create(photo_params)
    redirect_to vendor_path(@vendor)
  end

   def destroy
        @vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
        @foto = @vendor.fotos.find(params[:id])
        @foto.destroy
        redirect_to vendor_path(@vendor)
    end

  private

 def photo_params
  params.require(:foto).permit(:title, :image)
 end
end
```

foto.rb/model

```
class Foto < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :image
  belongs_to :vendor
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

migration file

```
class CreateFotos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :fotos do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.references :vendor, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

another migration file

```
class AddAttachmentImageToFotos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def self.up
     change_table :fotos do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :fotos, :image
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.submit 'Create Photo' %>
```

This should rename the button. For more options use the following link
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/submit

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

### 1. Pass a value to [submit_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag)

```
<%= f.submit 'Create Photo' %>
```

### 2. Use the [I18N module](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      foto:
        create:  "Create Photo"
```

This approach is better if you at some point intend to translate the application. It also makes it easy to use the same form for create and update and have the correct text for each.